# How can I transform a flow type into a js object?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype

Goal: I want to generate a UI form based on a flow type. In order to do that I need to convert the flow type into a JS object which I can then use to generate a form

I've looked at Flow-runtime. I've looked at the first 3 pages on Google.

```js
type user = {
 first_name: string,
 last_name: string
}
```

would convert to

```js
const user = {
 first_name: 'string',
 last_name: 'string'
}
```

Comment: Do you need help turning the `type` definition into the `const` declaration, help turning the `const` declaration into a form, help with both, or help with something else?

Comment: type definition into the const declaration

Comment: You'll need to run some script that inspects the Flow type and then outputs the `const` declaration before your code gets transpiled/shipped. I'm not sure what your build process is like so I can't say where/when this script should be/run. Depending on how particular your formatting is, this seems like a case for regex. I don't think there's a tool that allows "programmatic" access to a Flow type in the sense of `Object.entries` or `for...of` for a plain JS object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so kudos for Charles Pick for providing me with the answer:

```
//@flow
//@flow-runtime enable
import t, {reify} from 'flow-runtime';
import type {Type} from 'flow-runtime';

type User = {name: string};

const UserType = (reify: Type<User>);

console.log(UserType);
```